# Where to find activities created in a table in crm 2011 database

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I want to know, in which table will the service activity created will be stored in crm 2011 database. I'm trying to generate a report for that i need to know in which table all the service activities created will be stored. When i open ServiceAppointmentBase, its showing only ActivityId column and that is also null

Answer (score 6):

Crm stores data across multiple tables.

You should write you reports against the FilteredViews. e.g. FilteredServiceAppointment or FilteredAccount.

These views combine the various tables and also apply the permissions model of Crm.

Check out the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328467).

Answer (score 6):

All `Activity`s, including `ServiceAppointments`, are stored in a single table called `ActivityPointerBase` in the database.

In addition to the view referencing this table (`FilteredServiceAppointment`), the regular view to this table is called `ActivityPointer`, which you can access via Linq, and the filtered view is called `FilteredActivityPointer`, which you can access via SQL. It's worth noting that the Linq entity collection `ActivityPointerSet`, when accessed, points to the filtered view.

Each different type of `Activity` is identified by the `ActivityTypeCode`/`ActivityTypeCodeName` fields, which is how you'd know whether a particular activity is a `ServiceAppointment`.

As for warnings regarding manipulating the base tables, I figure you're an adult, so do whatever you want in the world to them, but you do need the filtered views for reporting.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't write reports against the base tables, use views instead. In this case, the view you are looking for is `dbo.FilteredServiceAppointment`

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328467.aspx